# How do I run a program that has cmd in it on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install a program on a raspberry pi which is supposed to be on windows, but apparently others have gotten it to run on a PI. The program uses bat files, but I can get around that just typing in the stuff to terminal. My main issue is this line- `cmd /k pipenv run python app.py amazon` from what I know cmd is command prompt, which is something I don't have.

IS there a way around this?

Comment: Can you run the command without `cmd /k`?

Comment: @Barmar it comes back with a long error message